# Correctly using the Excel match function to find a partial match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am desperately trying to make my excel do what I want. I want to find a string which is written in column B1 in my Column A1 to A5.
My string in column B2 shall be searched in A1:A5 as well.

Example:

```
______________
|  A    |  B  |
|_______|_____|
|       |     |
| 13234 | 12  |
|_______|_____|
|       |     |
| 15485 | 13  |
|_______|_____|
|       |     |
| 13234 | 23  |
|_______|_____|
|       |     |
| 78165 | 132 |
|_______|_____|
```

and now the output in C1 to C5 would be:

```
C1 = no match
C2 = A1,A3
C3 = A1,A3
C4 = A1,A3
```

I tried using the match function as follows:

```
=MATCH (A1, A1:A5, 0)
```

following the syntax taken from here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php

Comment: `MATCH` is not the correct function.  After all, 13 is not the same as 13234.  `FIND` can return an array of errors and numbers depending on whether the partial string is found, but, without VBA, it will be a problem getting the results you want.  Are the number of matching cells limited to just two (or some other value)?

Comment: I know that 13 is not the same, that's why my header is called "find a partial match", if you can express it better, feel free to suggest an edit. no the number I search for is is actually a key like "F45234GWE". Anyway thanks for help, I will check the find function.

Comment: I commented regarding exact match since you were using `0` for the `match_type` argument.  But, as I wrote, unless the number of possible matches is fixed or limited, you will need helper columns & complex formulas, or a simple VBA routine.

Comment: Damn it, My german version of excel will only accept german formulas :&

Comment: There are all kinds of translators out there. Do an internet search.

Comment: Hey Ron, I know, I used one. I was just wondering why english isn't accepted. Took me some time to find out that this is one of the problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function WhereIs(rIn As Range, rList As Range) As String
   Dim s1 As String, r As Range
   Dim s2 As String
   WhereIs = ""
   s1 = rIn.Text

   For Each r In rList
      s2 = r.Text
      If InStr(1, s2, s1) > 0 Then
         If WhereIs = "" Then
            WhereIs = r.Address(0, 0)
         Else
            WhereIs = WhereIs & "," & r.Address(0, 0)
         End If
      End If
   Next r

   If WhereIs = "" Then WhereIs = "no match"
End Function
```

where the first argument is the value being sought and the second argument is the list.

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=WhereIs(B1,A1:A4)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**